# How do I turn off WS_CAPTION style of a window (using user32.dll)?

Tags: c#, user32

I am embedding a 3rd party app into a panel on a C# Windows form (using `SetParent` from user32.dll).  I need to then turn off the title bar window style `WS_CAPTION` so that it looks like a part of the hosting application.

How do I change a window's style to accomplish this?

For sake of example, say `_hWnd` is the handle of the application to embed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SetWindowLong](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetWindowLong.html)(_hWnd, GWL_STYLE, [GetWindowLong](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowLong.html)(_hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_CAPTION);

Answer (score 3):

If memory serves, you might be able to do a GetWindowLong on the style, |= ~ WS_CAPTION on that value, and then SetWindowLong.  See those APIs in MSDN.

Also see:  http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=352963

Answer (score 2):

Take look at [WindowInterceptor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/WindowInterceptor.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use [GetWindowLong](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowLong.html) to retrieve the window style, mask the `WS_CAPTION` bits and then set the updated style using [SetWindowLong](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetWindowLong.html):

```
var style = GetWindowLong(_hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
SetWindowLong(_hWnd, GWL_STYLE, style & ~WS_CAPTION);
```

and with following helper code:

```
const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
const int WS_CAPTION = 0x00C00000;

[DllImport ("user32")]
private static extern int GetWindowLong(System.IntPtr hwnd, int nIndex);

[DllImport ("user32")]
private static extern int SetWindowLong(System.IntPtr hwnd, int index, int newLong);
```